# Planar graph embedding algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, planar-graphs

I'm looking for a planar graph embedding algorithm description. Actually, it would be nice if I knew at least names of these algorithms. The only one I know is called γ(gamma)-algorithm, and it has an only description in only one book(in Russian, so I don't even know English name of this algorithm), but I guess it's not the only one. Googling haven't given me any sufficient results too.

Comment: Googling "planar embedding algorithm" yields many results, among them this paper by Boyer and Myrvold which presents a fairly simple algorithm. Are you looking for something else?  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.8496&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @alon-amit thx, looks completery different from the one I read, I'll read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book Planar Graphs: Theory and Applications by T. Nishizeki and N. Chiba (Dover Press) has a discussion both of planarity testing and embedding algorithms.